# Unavoidable mirror modifier

Tags: sculpting

2.76b   using the default cube I subdivide edges with 10 cuts. Unselect all. Rotate the cube and box select only 1 side. P to separate by selection. 
Now in sculpt mode, all sculpting is mirrored about the center of the plane I separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sculpting can be made symmetrical in the toolbar.
Hit <kbd>T</kbd> to show it if it's hidden.

[image: symmetrical sculpt]